# Vaadin TwinColSelect and populate via other field

Tags: java, vaadin

I created an application that communicates with AD and have a text field and `TwinColSelect`.

I type in the text field *Mik* (I use text change listener from Vaadin) and my `listbuildier(TwinColSelect)` should be populated with results that start from this sequence, it's not happening but when I delete all what I have entered it's repainted and shows the result.

And I'm sure that all my code is working properly I will just add that all that is happening in the webapp in a new window.

Has anyone encountered a similar problem and have some hints?

---

Other questions:

How do I delete only the left side of `TwinColSelect` and leave the right one intact?

How can I get all (not only selected) items from the right side?

Comment: Have you set imediate=true on the text field ?
Using vaadin 6 oder 7? (Please split the second question in a question of it's own)

Comment: i've set imediate=true on text and twin col select, using vaadin 7. Second question have some answer here but not specific im looking for.
Im pretty stuck with it.

Comment: are the on text change events triggered at all ?

Comment: yes, i tried blur listener and it works as intended when field lose focus it populate properly, text change dont work as i would expect.

Comment: I have a feeling that you are using `TextField.getValue()` to update your `TwinColSelect` instead of the `TextChangeEvent` argument received by your `TextChangeListener`. Am I Right ?

Comment: yea, i messed up code and errors like that occured i forgot to say its solved.
Thanks for answer anyway (i tried boutch listener btw)